# What version of OpenSSH is available on macOS Big Sur (11.0.1)?

Tags: macos, ssh

I am currently running Mojave which has the following

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Before moving to macOS Big Sur, I'd like to know the default version of SSH on it.

Comment: Wait for Big Sur to show up at https://opensource.apple.com

Comment: To whomever downvoted this question, why? It certainly a litigate question.

Comment: @anki Thanks I was not aware of this very useful page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Terminal**, using a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** (11.0.1), `ssh -V` returns:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```